# User rolls back all edits to his question -- leave it alone?

Tags: discussion, editing

I can understand that users might feel a little defensive about their posts and not understand edits that are made to it.  In the case of this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177358/generating-temporary-passowds-token-using-this-simple-method), the OP has rolled back edits to his question twice.  The edits (in full disclosure, one was mine) appear to improve the quality of the question: the title was unclear as written, contained a typo/misspelling, and formatting of the post body left much to be desired.

I feel like the edits significantly improve the question, and consequently improve the site, but obviously the user strongly doesn't want the edits to take place.  I'm not going to mess with his post again, but I'm curious how others would approach it.

Comment: I ended up locking the post even after direct contact still resulted in the user insisting on misspelling words.

Comment: It's baffling that OP didn't just insist on their own phrasing (which sometimes makes sense) but wanted to keep their typos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flagging for mod attention is useful. Adding a comment can also engage the user to get them to stop rolling back (as I have now done).

Some people are very protective of their "voice" and any edit is seen as a personal assault. But we are here not just to answer the question in the moment, but to have that question and answer available to others who might also have the same question. Proper spelling and clear phrasing help make that possible.